# CFT Template error: unresolved condition dependency UseDBSnapshot in Fn::If

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Trying to create a CFT for RDS which can handle both the scenarios
creating a new RDS Aurora MySQL cluster and
create a RDS cluster with a existing DB Cluster Snapshot

Here is what I tried,

I have provide the below conditions section of the template

```
"UseDbSnapshot" : {
              "Fn::Not" : [
                  {
                      "Fn::Equals":[
                            {"Ref": "DBSnapshotName"},
                            ""
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

and referenced in Resource section as below

```
"RDSCluster1": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
        "Condition": "isResourceCreate",
        "Properties": {
            "Engine": "aurora",
            "DBSubnetGroupName": {
                "Ref": "DBSubnetGroup"
            },
            "DBClusterParameterGroupName": {
                "Ref": "RDSDBClusterParameterGroup"
            },
            "DBSnapshotIdentifier" : {
                "Fn::If" : [
                  "UseDBSnapshot",
                  {"Ref" : "DBSnapshotName"},
                  {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}
                ]
              },
            "MasterUsername": {
                "Ref": "DbUser"
            },
            "MasterUserPassword": {
                "Ref": "MasterUserPassword"
            },
            "StorageEncrypted" : true,
            "KmsKeyId" : {
                "Ref": "KmsKeyId"
            },
            "VpcSecurityGroupIds": [
                {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "DBAccessSecurityGroup",
                        "GroupId"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Port": "3306",
            "BackupRetentionPeriod": "1"
        },
        "DeletionPolicy": "Snapshot"
    }
```

The condition "isResourceCreate" is satisfied but I am getting below error

Template error: unresolved condition dependency UseDBSnapshot in Fn::If

Could you please help me here.

Have looked up online link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html
and created this CFT.

Let me know if you require any more details.

Comment: Can you provide complete template? Your current one does not even show paramters.

Comment: You have a typo. UseDbSnapshot != UseDBSnapshot

Comment: updated my CFT stack code here

Comment: now, I have the below error after correcting the template Both SnapshotIdentifier and MasterUsername cannot be specified even though I have used `"Fn::If" : [     "UseDbSnapshot",      {"Ref" : "DBSnapshotName"},      {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"} ] ` @OleksiiDonoha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are restoring DB from snapshot, you **can't provide** `MasterUsername` and `MasterUserPassword`. These values will be [inherited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html) from the snapshot, so you have to make them **optional**.

> If you specify the SourceDBInstanceIdentifier or DBSnapshotIdentifier property, don't specify this property. The value is **inherited from the source DB instance or snapshot**.